# Serial port causes deadlock after some non fixed number of writes (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, io, bluetooth, serial-port

I've been writing a serial port application in C++ that can handle two way communication over a virtual serial port to a Bluetooth stack I've written for an Arm microprocessor.

The embedded side I'm pretty sure is fine because in another application that primarily receives data from the microprocessor never causes a crash. In this application I'm sending binary data from the C++ serial port application to the microprocessor in 64 byte chunks with a simple protocol to control when to stop sending and so on.

The way I handle both applications are pretty similar so i'm wondering if there's a difference when i'm sending data instead of receiving it that causes an issue.

The code is written and debugged in Visual Studio 2010.

**One thing i find really unusual is this application works with a USB to serial wired connection but deadlocks over a virtual com port!! simultaneously debugging the uprocessor there doesn't seem to be any issue on that side so what could cause this problem?**

**EDIT**

Hacving looked deeper into the callstack the hang happens executing:

> ntdll.dll!_ZwWriteFile@36()  + 0x15 bytes

It basically goes like this:

**Initialise:**

```
brate = CBR_112500; 
com_name[0]='C'; 
com_name[1]='O'; 
com_name[2]='M';
com_name[3]=com_name[4]=com_name[5]=com_name[6]=0;


printf("Select COM Port: ");
scanf("%s", &com_name[3]);

if (Connect(com_name,brate)!=SLCONNECT_OK)
{
    printf("\t\t\t\t....Could not open to port, exiting\r\n");
}
```

**Connect:**

Here I originally create a second thread to handle reads but decided that was probably the cause of the deadlock. I then removed the thread and ran everything synchronously but still had the same issue.

```
int Connect(const char *portname,int baudrate)
{

    DCB dev_cont_block;

    if (port_h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return(SLCONNECT_ALREADY_CONNECTED);
    }

    if(strlen(portname)>4) // if COM10 or above use \\.\COM10
    {
        char *longportname;
        int i;
        longportname = (char *) malloc(strlen(portname)+5);
        if(longportname != NULL)
        {
            longportname[0] = '\\';
            longportname[1] = '\\';
            longportname[2] = '.';
            longportname[3] = '\\';
            for(i=0;i<strlen(portname);i++)
                longportname[4+i]=portname[i];
            longportname[4+i] = 0;

            port_h = CreateFile(longportname, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE ,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);
            delete(longportname);
        }
        else
            return(SLCONNECT_CONNECT_FAILED);
    }
    else
        port_h = CreateFile(portname, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE ,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

    if (port_h==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return(SLCONNECT_CONNECT_FAILED);
    }

    if (GetCommState(port_h,&dev_cont_block))
    {
        dev_cont_block.BaudRate = baudrate;
        dev_cont_block.ByteSize = 8;
        dev_cont_block.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
        dev_cont_block.fParity = FALSE;
        dev_cont_block.Parity = NOPARITY;
        dev_cont_block.fOutxCtsFlow = TRUE;
        dev_cont_block.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
        dev_cont_block.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;

        if (!SetCommState(port_h, &dev_cont_block)) return(SLCONNECT_SETUP_PORT_FAILED);
    }
    else return(SLCONNECT_SETUP_PORT_FAILED);

    PurgeComm(port_h,PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
    keepLooping=1;
    ///_beginthread(Watcher,0,this);
    //WatcherThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, Watcher, this, 0, NULL);



    return(SLCONNECT_OK);
}
```

**Main application**

Here I wait for a user command to start, send it to the uprocessor, wait for a response, send package, wait for response etc till the complete binary file is sent.

I've omitted some irrelevant parts here like how i handle the end of file and so on.

```
sendbuf[0] = 'x'; // The 'x' is just a placeholder
sendbuf[1] = 'x'; 
sendbuf[2] = 'x';
sendbuf[3] = 'x';
sendbuf[4] = 'x';
sendbuf[5] = 'x';
sendbuf[6] = 'x';
sendbuf[7] = 'x';


printf("Press 1 to begin Upgrade\r\n");


if(_getch() == '1')
{
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    Send('x');
    if(Send('x') == SLSEND_OK )
    {
        printf("=> Note 'Set Firmware Mode'");
    }
}

while(1)
{


while(true)
{
    ClearCommError(port_h,&l_dwErrors, &l_ComStat);
    if(l_ComStat.cbInQue)
    {
        ReadFile(port_h, &data, 1, &Received, NULL);
        if(Received == 1)
        {
            Received = DllRxD(DataBuffer,64, data );
            if(Received > 0)
            {
                if (DataBuffer[0] == 'x') //Note received
                {
                    printf("\n\r=> Note ");
                    if(DataBuffer[3] == 'x' && DataBuffer[4] == 'x')
                    {

                        if(DataBuffer[5] == 'x')
                        {
                            if(DataBuffer[6] == 0x00)
                            {
                                printf("'Firmware Packet Received Sucessfully'");
                                result = 1;
                                break;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                printf("'Error In Packet Message [0x0%d]'",(unsigned int)DataBuffer[6]);
                                result = -1;
                                break;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(DataBuffer[3] =='x' && DataBuffer[4] == 'x')
                    {
                        if(DataBuffer[5] == 'x')
                        {
                            printf("Mode has changed to: Firmware Upgrade Mode");
                            result = 2;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    printf("=> ERRROR 'Unexpected Message'");
                    result =  -2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}//while(true)  

    if(result == 1 || result == 2)
    {

        UpdateCRC('x', &crc); 
        UpdateCRC('x', &crc); 
        UpdateCRC('x', &crc);
        UpdateCRC('x', &crc);
        UpdateCRC('x', &crc);
        UpdateCRC('x', &crc);
        UpdateCRC('x', &crc);
        UpdateCRC('x', &crc);

        for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            fread(&Packet[i],1,1,pFile);
            if(feof(pFile))
                Packet[i] = 0xFF;

            if(Packet[i] == 'x')
            {
                UpdateCRC(Packet[i],&crc);
                UpdateCRC(Packet[i],&crc);

            }
            else
                UpdateCRC(Packet[i],&crc);
        }

        UpdateCRC('x', &crc); 
        UpdateCRC('x', &crc); 


        Send(x); //framing
        Send(x);
        Send('x');
        Send('x');
        Send('x');
        Send('x');
        Send('x');
        Send('x');

        for (i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            if(Packet[i] == 'x')
            {
                Send(Packet[i]); **//this set of sends is where i receive the deadlock error message, it's not always the same place it happens though**
                Send(Packet[i]);
            }
            else

                Send(Packet[i]);
        }

        Send('x');
        Send('x');
        Send((crc >> 8));
        if(Send((crc & 0xFF)) == SLSEND_OK)
        {
            printf("\n\r\t\t\t\t....Packet Sent (%u Bytes Total)",counter*64);
        }
```

**Send**

This is the actual send function

```
int Send(unsigned char sdata)
{
    unsigned long bytesWritten=0;
    unsigned int rtn;

    **//This is where the program stops in the source code i can view**
    //Error received is "this is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from it's current function"
    rtn = WriteFile(port_h,&sdata,1,&bytesWritten,NULL);

    if (rtn)
        return(SLSEND_OK);
    else
        return(SLSEND_UNKNOWN_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert at all at this. But i have played around a bit with the serialports..

Im not sure if i may be missing something when i read your code, but i dont see if you set the timeouts for either write or read.

Also, how do you handle the Data Terminal Ready line? I had all sorts of strange things happen due to that..

Comment: I've started handling timeouts now and the data terminal ready line, i've tried enabling and disabling it (i'm using no real hardware lines since it's all over bluetooth) and still have the same deadlocks.

"This is the next statement to execute when the thread returns from the current function" is on the line where i call writefile

Answer (score 0):

dev_cont_block.fOutxCtsFlow = TRUE;

> Blockquote
>   fOutxCtsFlow
>   If this member is TRUE, the CTS (clear-to-send) signal is monitored for output flow control. If this member is TRUE and CTS is turned off, output is suspended until CTS is sent again.